# OnClick Javascript button to launch a flow

Tags: javascript, custom-button, visual-workflow

Im trying to launch a flow from a button using javascript. In my code so far I have:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")}

String base = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl();
alert(base);
```

However when I click the button I get:

```
Unexpected identifier
```

instead of the URL. What is it I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call Apex Code methods like that; you're in a JavaScript context. You'll probably want to start off with something like this:

```
{!RequireScript('/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js')}
{!RequireScript('/soap/ajax/34.0/apex.js')}

var baseUrl = sforce.apex.execute('Utils','getSalesforceBaseUrl', {});
alert(baseUrl);
```

You'll need a corresponding class:

```
global class Utils {
    webservice static string getSalesforceBaseUrl() {
        return URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl();
    }
}
```

---

You might also have different options available, depending on your exact context. This is only one possible option. For example, you could write a Visualforce page with a trivial controller:

```
<apex:page contentType="text/plain" controller="Utils" 
           showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false"
           standardStylesheets="false" showChat="false">{!salesforceBaseUrl}</apex:page>
```

With the appropriate method in Utils:

```
    public string getSalesforceBaseUrl() {
        return URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl();
    }
```